# How to select by two values from same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple db which contains users and their hobbies. Relation is many-to-many, so there are three tables. I need to select all users by two specific hobbies. For example they should do both football and basketball.

I'm new to SQL and thought that AND operator will solve it, but it doesn't work for me. My query is

```
SELECT u.name
FROM hobby h
INNER JOIN user_hobby uh on h.id = uh.hobby_id
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = uh.user_id
WHERE h.name = 'Basketball' AND h.name = 'Football';
```

I tried a couple of variations - no result. I know it might be easy, sorry for asking that type of question, but just didn't find a proper example of my case in the internet, so will be thankful for any help!

Comment: Version 1, add an EXISTS condition for the second hobby.

Comment: Version 2, join user_hobby twice,

Comment: Version 3, do a GROUP BY. use HAVING to make sure both hobbies are there. (Probably best performance.)

Comment: Simply produce two separate joins. First with lets say, basketball. Then another one between basketball and football.

Comment: @jarlh Could you guys please show me how these queries look?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all users that play either basketball or football:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM hobby h
INNER JOIN user_hobby uh on h.id = uh.hobby_id
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = uh.user_id
WHERE h.name IN('Basketball', 'Football');
```

If you want to select all users that play both basketball and football:

```
SELECT N.name
FROM
(
    SELECT u.name, h.name AS 'Hobby_Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Hobby_Count'
    FROM hobby h
    JOIN user_hobby uh on h.id = uh.hobby_id
    JOIN user u on u.id = uh.user_id
    WHERE h.name IN('Basketball', 'Football')
    GROUP BY u.name, h.name
) N
GROUP BY N.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Yeah., I need users that only do both basketball and football. Tried second option, but it returned only one user, but should return three of them.

Comment: Some of the data might not be correct with one of the joins.  Can you please post the data for the 3 users for the 3 tables?

Comment: You can also run this query to see if more than a count of 2 is appearing, or change to HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2.  This would indicate duplicate records.  SELECT u.name, h.name AS 'Hobby_Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Hobby_Count'
    FROM hobby h
    JOIN user_hobby uh on h.id = uh.hobby_id
    JOIN user u on u.id = uh.user_id
    WHERE h.name IN('Basketball', 'Football')
    GROUP BY u.name, h.name

Comment: I tried and it didn't work either. Maybe I did something wrong. Thank you anyway for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.  It works for me and I use it often.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM hobby h
INNER JOIN user_hobby uh on h.id = uh.hobby_id
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = uh.user_id
WHERE h.name in ('Basketball', 'Football');
```

Comment: OP wants users having both Basketball and Football, not just one of them.

Comment: Yeah, IN and OR it's not that, as I want to get users that do both hobbies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).